# BeautifulSoup can't find class that exists on webpage?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I am trying to scrape the following webpage **https://www.scoreboard.com/uk/football/england/premier-league/**,

Specifically the scheduled and finished results. Thus I am trying to look for the elements with `class = "stage-finished" or "stage-scheduled"`. However when I scrape the webpage and print out what **page_soup** contains, it doesn't contain these elements.

I found another SO question with an answer saying that this is because it is loaded via AJAX and I need to look at the XHR under the network tab on chrome dev tools to find the file thats loading the necessary data, however it doesn't seem to be there?

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv
import datetime

myurl = "https://www.scoreboard.com/uk/football/england/premier-league/"
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(myurl, headers=headers)

page_soup = soup(page.content, "html.parser")

scheduled = page_soup.select(".stage-scheduled")
finished = page_soup.select(".stage-finished")
live = page_soup.select(".stage-live")
print(page_soup)
print(scheduled[0])
```

The above code throws an error of course as there is no content in the scheduled array.

My **question** is, how do I go about getting the data I'm looking for?

I copied the contents of the XHR files to a notepad and searched for stage-finished and other tags and found nothing. Am I missing something easy here?

Comment: If it is indeed a page loaded with javascript like you suspect, then you may want to try using `selenium` which can handle this.

Comment: @MattCremeens Appreciate the resonse, is this the only way? I ask as I'm really new to python and webscraping, so this seems pretty intimidating for me to wrap my head around how to use

Comment: It's the only way I've found, but I think you'll find it pretty easy to use. The coding changes are minimal. Start with `pip install selenium` and have a look here: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/ and scroll down to the selenium section.

Comment: If the content you're looking for is dynamically generated by client-side javascript - as seems to be the case here - then you don't have any other choice than using a headless browser (selenium or else) indeed. Note that this has nothing to do with Python itself, you'd get the very same problem whatever the language.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you do `page_soup.select('.stage-scheduled > td:nth-of-type(2)')` and then `print(scheduled[0].getText())`?

Comment: @MattCremeens It gives the same error saying that scheduled[0] is out of bounds unfortunately. In the actual page_soup content i've trawled through, there is no 'stage-scheduled' class at all, so i'm sure it's getting loaded with JS

Comment: Yes, then I think `selenium` is your best bet. You can use the same css selectors you would use in `BeautifulSoup`. You will need to make sure you have some sort of driver installed, like the chromedriver. You can download from the internet.

Comment: @MattCremeens Okay cheers, I'm finding it pretty tricky using this, but if it's the only way I'm sure I'll figure it out

Comment: If you get stuck, make a new question and pattern it after this one. It was well written, hence I upvoted it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The page is JavaScript rendered. You need Selenium. Here is some code to start on:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.scoreboard.com/uk/football/england/premier-league/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
stages = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('stage-scheduled')
driver.close()
```

Or you could pass `driver.content` in to the `BeautifulSoup` method. Like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
```

Note:
You need to install a webdriver first. I installed chromedriver.

Good luck!