# BeautifulSoup class searching, no results

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse code of [this](https://www.awf.edu.pl/pracownik/wyszukiwarka-pracownikow?result_5251_result_page=3&queries_search_query=&category_kategorie=wydzia_wychowania_fizycznego&search_page_5251_submit_button=Szukaj&current_result_page=1&results_per_page=20&submitted_search_category=&mode=results) site and extract URL of the results. But when using `find_all` command I get an empty list as output. I checked manually the HTML code that I download from the site, and it contains the appropriate class.
If somebody could point out where I make a mistake or show a better solution I would be grateful!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


page = requests.get("https://www.awf.edu.pl/pracownik/wyszukiwarka-pracownikow?result_5251_result_page=3&queries_search_query=&category_kategorie=wydzia_wychowania_fizycznego&search_page_5251_submit_button=Szukaj&current_result_page=1&results_per_page=20&submitted_search_category=&mode=results")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'search-item photo')
```

`

I've also tried to use this code below to just find all links on the site and then separate that what I need, but in this instance, I get only parent tag. if in tag 'a' is nested another tag 'a' it is skipped, and from documentation, I thought it also would be included in the output.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


page = requests.get("https://www.awf.edu.pl/pracownik/wyszukiwarka-pracownikow?result_5251_result_page=3&queries_search_query=&category_kategorie=wydzia_wychowania_fizycznego&search_page_5251_submit_button=Szukaj&current_result_page=1&results_per_page=20&submitted_search_category=&mode=results")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('a')
```

[BeautifulSoup can't find class that exists on webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52408701/beautifulsoup-cant-find-class-that-exists-on-webpage)

I found this answer to a similar question, but in my case, I can see the HTML code that I want to find in my console when I use `print(soup.prettify())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem you are facing is linked to the way you are parsing `page.content`.

*replace:*

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

*with:*

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
```

hope this helps.

Comment: It works, can you explain why? If I understand correctly, it's because HTML parsing is not supported by newest versions of BeautifulSoup library, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I’m not 100% sure of the reason but as far as I know your supposition is correct. (As a rule of thumb I always use lxml)