# Parse table data from coin market cap in python with bs4

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This seems like such an easy script to write, but it's driving me crazy.

Just trying to parse some table data for a single coin on CMC. I don't know why something like this doesn't work:

```
import pandas
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# link = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/?start={}&end={}'
link = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/xrp/historical-data/'

def get_coinmarketcap_info(url,s_date,e_date):
    response = requests.get(url.format(s_date,e_date))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")

    for items in soup.select("table.table tr.text-right"):
        date = items.select_one("td.text-left").get_text(strip=True)
        close = items.select_one("td[data-format-market-cap]").find_previous_sibling().get_text(strip=True)
        volume = items.select_one("td[data-format-market-cap]").get_text(strip=True)
        marketcap = items.select_one("td[data-format-market-cap]").find_next_sibling().get_text(strip=True)
        yield date,close,volume,marketcap

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dataframe = (elem for elem in get_coinmarketcap_info(link,s_date='20130428',e_date='20191020'))
    df = pandas.DataFrame(dataframe)
    print(df)
```

My underlying question is why does bs4 just not work (could totally be user error), but something like this, with just a basic `soup.find` or `soup.select` with one of those crazy class names, literally never works for me. Regardless of the website:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import html5lib

# url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ripple/historical-data/?start=20130428&end=20180802"
url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/xrp/historical-data/"
content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')

table = soup.select('div', {'class': 'b4d71h-2 hgYnhQ'})
```

Also - i'd love if someone can explain why website html always has these weird crazy class names/strings - rather than something easy to read. Is this because these strings are dynamic or are they not meant to be parsed or is there something i should be looking for a little higher up in the html to parse first?? Maybe there's a better source to pull the data from too within the inspect element - is there a place to go search for within the inspect element that might have an underlying link to the table data?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup can't find class that exists on webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52408701/beautifulsoup-cant-find-class-that-exists-on-webpage)

Comment: will look in a few minutes - after this dumb all hands meeting. thx for the suggestion though